# Looping over vector of vectors and appending to a new vector

Tags: c++, stl

I want to loop over vect, call a function on each element, perform an operation between both the results and append that to a new vector.
Is there a better way to do this?

```
std::vector<int> vect = {{1,2},{3,4}};
std::vector<double> out(vect.size());
for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++){
       double v = somefunction(vect[i][0]) - somefunction(vect[i][1]);
       out.push_back(v);
    }
```

Comment: What's the type of `vect`?  Do you need to retain its contents, or can you move from it?  It would be better to post a full function, along with the relevant headers, to show more precisely what you want.

Comment: une210 There is no such member function as pushback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `std::transform` can be used for.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<double> out(vect.size());

std::transform(vect.cbegin(), vect.cend(), out.begin(), [](const auto& inner)
    { return somefunction(inner.front()) - somefunction(inner.back()); });
```

This assumes that `vect` is a container of size `2` with `front()` and `back()` member functions that do what one would expect them to do.

Comment: Oh, I did not know `std::transform`. I upvoted since I think your answer is much better (and concise) than mine.

Comment: For types that are expensive to default-construct (not `double`), it would be better to create an empty `out`, reserve capacity, and pass a `std::back_inserter` as the transform's output iterator.  But this answer is fine for `double` elements.

Comment: @TobySpeight Good point. In addition to the default construction of `double`s being cheap I also wanted to keep close to the original code in the question.

Comment: Hi! Wouldn't this work even if vect has more than 2 elements?

Comment: Yes. It works for any size of `vect`, including zero.

Comment: @acraig5075 Hm, the OP has `vect[i][0]` and `vect[i][1]`, which I replaced with `front()` and `back()`. If the size is not 2 then my answer results in a different behavior compared to the snippet in the question, no?

Comment: Can it not be used this way?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57526667/error-in-lambda-functions-transform-difference?noredirect=1#comment101522840_57526667

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `vect` is a `std::vector <std::vector <double>>` as it seems to be, you could simply write:

```
std::vector <double> out;
for(size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i)
{
    out.push_back(someFunction(vect[i][0]) - someFunction(vect[i][1]));
}
```

or

```
std::vector <double> out;
for(auto & v : vect)
{
    out.push_back(someFunction(v[0]) - someFunction(v[1]));
}
```

You don't have to initialize `out` as you did because `push_back()` will add another element at the end of what you already have added in the construction.

---

Note that if `vect` only contains vectors of size two, you can use `std::pair` instead, for example:

```
std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> vect;
```

And replace the previous loop by:

```
std::vector <double> out;
for(size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i)
{
    out.push_back(someFunction(vect[i].first) - someFunction(vect[i].second));
}
```

or

```
std::vector <double> out;
for(auto & v : vect)
{
    out.push_back(someFunction(v.first) - someFunction(v.second));
}
```